# Linux Autotest: AttributeError

Tags: linux, kernel, virtualbox, autotest

I just started trying Autotest for Linux kernel. I installed Ubuntu 16.04 into VirtualBox. And then downloaded autotest and the linux developer package.

When I run the included tests I get errors similar to "AttributeError: xxx object has no attribute yyy". There is a lot of them! I expected it to work straight out of the box.

The only step that I skipped was setting up the host side. I am wondering if it is the source of my errors. The docs say to run the host side once to set everything up. But I don't want to connect to the cloud etc ... Can I just run everything on the client side? Is there a way to set it up to run client only?

Any packages that I am missing?

Thanks!

Comment: This question needs to be a lot more specific to be actionable. We don't even know which specific tests you're trying to run (yes, it might happen with all of them, but that doesn't mean we can figure out that general issue without knowing *in detail* how a specific example fails).

Comment: ...if you gave specific values for "xxx" and "yyy", that would at least be a place to start. As it is, you're giving us nothing at all to go on. Those exceptions are attached to Python stack traces -- those stack traces point out specific lines of code where errors originate from. That's *important information*, and I don't know how you expect folks to know what your immediate problem is without that information.